# Control buttons on "Golden DMC" are grey when select my DMR

Tags: android, upnp, dlna

I wrote a `DMR` for android with the open source project `CyberLink4Java`. Test it with tools that `DLNA group` released *(Golden DMC & Gloden DMS)*. I create a Device with proper description file. Now it can push play.

*But it don't support control by the DMC*.

```
On the DMC UI, the control buttons(play, pause and stop) are grey.
```

There must be some data exchange to tell the `DMC` that it support these controls during the `DMR service start`. But I can't find in the spec. Any idea on what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to expose transport-controlling actions that are valid at a given time is the `CurrentTransportActions` state variable and the corresponding method `GetCurrentTransportActions`. These features are optional but conditionally required so if you implement one you need to implement both. `CurrentTransportActions` is like most variables in AVTransport: it's not evented on its own but value changes will be included in LastChange events. This is all documented in [AVTransport service definition](http://www.upnp.org/specs/av/UPnP-av-AVTransport-v3-Service.pdf).

That said, mostly a DMC can figure out the valid actions based on DMR state even if the above features aren't supported: e.g. if AVTransportURI is empty, showing playback controls doesn't make sense.